# Very simple to state, but..... (Quadrilateral and its diagonal's adventure.)

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

> Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral. $BA$$\cap$ $CD$=$K$, $BC$$\cap $$AD$=$M$. $O$ is the intersection of the diagonals. The segment parallel to $MK$ and goes through $O$ meet at sides $BC$ and $AD$ at $E$ and $F$, respectively. Then prove that $EO$=$OF$.

My try: Let $BF$$\cap $$MK$=$P$ and $BD$$\cap$ $MK$=$Q$. From here, if we can prove $P, D, E$ are collinear, we can say $MQ=QP$ by the Ceva theorem. Moreover it will be $EO$=$OF$. However, I can't prove it at all. Can you guys give me some hints?

I don't know any complex, vector and projective geometry, so please consider giving me an Euclidean one.

Comment: What is the meaning of  BA∩ CD= K?

Comment: @Moti "The intersection between line $BA$ and line $CD$ is point $K$".

Comment: The segment parallel to $MK$ which goes through $O$ can also meet the sides $AB$ and $CD$ instead of $BC$ and $AD$, right. I suppose in that case the result is still valid.

Comment: In fact, the problem said the segment parallel to $MK$ which is in quadrilateral bisects with point $O$. Since it's a bit troublesome to write the solution without marking everything, I named everything. In other words it will still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $P=BF\cap MK$, let $P=BF\cap ED$.  Then use [Desargues' Theorem](http://users.math.uoc.gr/%7Epamfilos/eGallery/problems/Desargues.pdf) with triangles $AFB$ and $CED$ to show $P$ is on line $MK$.

Complete the proof as you suggest, with Ceva's theorem.

Desargues' Theorem is traditionally a theorem of projective geometry, but it can be easily proved using Menalaus' Theorem, as shown on page 2 of the reference above.